# How to create 32 bit System DSN in Windows 7 64 bit machine using c#

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit, dllimport, dsn

I need to create 32 bit System DSN programitically in Windows 7 OS which is 64 bit. I used the following code.

```
[DllImport("ODBCCP32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool SQLConfigDataSource(UInt32 hwndParent, RequestFlags fRequest,string lpszDriver, string lpszAttributes);

public static void CreateDSN() 
{
    string strDrivername = "SQL Server";
    string strConfig = "DSN=test6\0" +
                       "Database=Test\0" +
                       "Description=StackOverflow Sample\0" +
                       "Server=10.10.11.16\0" +                                     
                       "Trusted_Connection=Yes\0";

    bool success = SQLConfigDataSource(0, RequestFlags.ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN, strDrivername, strConfig);
}
```

Above code working. but it is creating 64 bit ODBC System DSN. Kindly help me to create 32 bit DSN.

Thanks,
Karthik P

Comment: You are using the 64-bit version of ODBCCP32.DLL.  Creating a 32-bit DSN requires using the 32-bit version.  Only way to do that is to change your EXE project's Platform target setting to x86.  As long as you are hard-coding this, using a simple .reg file is the much simpler solution.